# jQuery Ajax fails; File is loaded correctly

Tags: jquery

i'm having trouble using jQuery (v1.9.1) ajax.

Here is the really simple js (`common.js`):

```
var BASE_URL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/';

$(document).ready(function(){
    //load menu
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : BASE_URL + 'menu.json',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(){alert('D');})
    .fail(function(){alert('F');})
    .always(function(){alert('A');});
});
```

According to Firebug the file (`menu.json`) is loaded correctly. but the problem ist that i always get the alert-messages `F` and `A`.

So why is this really simple code not working? I just can't figure it out.

If needed here is the correspoding html part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    </head>
....
```

both javascript files are loaded correctly.

**UPDATE**

Here is the content of `menu.json` (yep it's static)

```
[
    {
        "name": "Home",
        "url": "#main"
},
{
        "name": "WTF",
        "url": "#wtf"
    }
]
```

Comment: First guess: `menu.json` doesn't contain valid JSON. Can we see its content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the transfer succeeded doesn't mean that the AJAX call did.  Most likely your response is not valid JSON.  You may also need to ensure that the web server returns the correct `Content-type` for JSON, i.e. `application/json`.

**EDIT** confirmed - JSON requires that the keys (and string values) be enclosed in **double quotes**

The other common reason is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing security issues, although that shouldn't be a factor here since you're downloading from the same site as the current page.

Also, there's really no need to specify `BASE_URL` - just use the path `/menu.json`

Comment: Ok. Just put double quotes around it (i will update the post in a second). But it still is not working. I guess it is because In the "Response-Header" section there is no `Content-Type` Header. See [here](http://data.a-morillon.de/images/jq_ajax.JPG)

Comment: So just found the error. It still was just a error within the json file. Thanks for pointing me there.